# sum selected sql

Tags: mysql, sql

input data:

[image]

query:

```
  SELECT NumOM, Id_site,
    SocieteClient,
    Reference,
    Designation,
    SUM (NbPiecesCTR) AS NbPiecesCTR,
  FROM  
  ( SELECT DISTINCT 
    OMpda.NumOM AS NumOM,   
    OMpda.Id_site AS Id_site,
    OMpda.NumTerminal AS NumTerminal,   
    OMpda.SocieteClient AS SocieteClient,   
    OMpda.Utilisateur AS Utilisateur,   
    OMpda.AJ AS AJ, 
    OMpda.Datesaisie AS Datesaisie, 

    OMpda.Période AS Période,   
    OMpda.Reference AS Reference,   
    OMpda.Designation AS Designation,   
    OMpda.NumBac AS NumBac, 
    OMpda.Demarrage AS Demarrage,   
    OMpda.FinOM AS FinOM,   
    OMpda.NbPiecesCTR AS NbPiecesCTR,
    FROM OMpda
   )
  WHERE     
    Id_site={pNomSite}
    AND Datesaisie={pDateOM}
    AND NumOM={pNumom}

  GROUP BY Id_site,
    NumOM, 
    SocieteClient,
    Datesaisie,
    Reference,
    Designation
```

I WANT TO HAVE THE SUM BY USR FOR 
THE SUM OF Inspected parts qty FOR USR XXX  360 and NO 720

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except the ones that arguments to set functions. `GROUP BY NumOM, Id_site,
    SocieteClient,
    Reference,
    Designation`

Comment: Please don't type in ALL CAPS, and clarify what you mean, with an example of the output dataset that you want; your description, as well as being VERY LOUD, is also very unclear.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Utilisateur,Inspected parts qty FROM OMpda GROUP BY Utilisateur,Inspected parts
```

Difficult to understand what you need. Heres what will give you 720 qty.
(Ignoring the query you provided in your post.)

Comment: I need to have the sum by quantity without duplicates as on the screenshot 360 instead 720